# How to draw rectangle over contour in JavaCV?

Tags: java, opencv, contour

I found contours in an image by using `cvFindContours`. Now I want to draw rectangle over them. Am I right that I should use the `cvBoundingRect` method? The first parameter of this function is a `CvArr` object, but I found that the contours are `CvSeq` objects. How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Solved.

You can cast `CvSeq` to `CvArr`